# Can a phonemically aspirated consonant have an unaspirated allophone?

Tags: phonetics, aspiration

in My native language, Georgian there exist a set of phonemic aspirated consonants /pʰ tʰ kʰ/ which are said to be aspirated in all positions.

though recently I noticed that when the aspirated plosives follow a voiceless fricative for example /ʃ/ as in [/ʃtʰɑntʰkʰmɑ/](/https://voca.ro/1nwQeocmDBtU) ("to absorb"), they sound indistinguishable from voiced stops to my ears and it's difficult to perceive the difference between them.

is it possible that the /tʰ/ in /ʃtʰ/ is unaspirated and that's why it sounds like a /d/?

Comment: I predict the answer to all future "is it possible for an X phoneme to have a non-X allophone?" is going to be "yes". There's no phonetic property I know of that is always maintained across allophones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Georgian has a three-way laryngeal contrast in stops, which is often treated as /pʰ b p'/. If supposed /pʰ/ is realized phonetically as [p, pʰ] depending on context, then it is an open question whether that phoneme is phonemically /p/ or /pʰ/. English is thought to have underlying /p/ where [pʰ] is a (foot-initial) predictable variant, however it is equally plausible to say that English has underlying /pʰ/ where [p] is found in foot-medial position. So we would need to see what the actual distribution of aspirated and unaspirated stops in Georgian is, to see whether the /p/ hypothesis is the better analysis, or the /pʰ/ analysis.

It is possible that in Georgian aspiration is actually contrastive and supposed voiced stops like /b/ are unaspirated – re-phonemicization of English /p,b/ as /pʰ,p/ has been proposed. We therefore need to see the evidence that Georgian has the phonemic system /pʰ b p'/ rather than /pʰ p p'/. We also need to see the evidence for the analysis /ʃ**tʰ**ɑntʰkʰmɑ/ rather than /ʃ**d**ɑntʰkʰmɑ/. Grapheme-selection is not particularly compelling evidence for a specific phonological analysis.

Comment: actually according to this [study](https://zenodo.org/record/890293#.YukbgGQjhPw) the so-called voiced stops are realized as voiceless in initial positions, in my opinion the voiced stops in Georgian should be analyzed as /b̥ d̥ ɡ̊/ with the explanation that they are realized as voiced in intervocalic positions and at the end of a word they might be devoiced to /pʰ tʰ kʰ.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting a comment on one of your earlier questions:

> Given that [ɾ] and [ʔ] are attested as allophones, or [s] and [k], I would think the answer to any "can X and Y potentially be allophones?" question would have to be "yes". Is there any reason you think it's *not* possible for a phoneme to have both ejective and non-ejective allophones?

Or in this case, aspirated and non-aspirated. I don't know of any phonetic property that is always maintained across allophones.

If you're looking for an example, English "voiceless" stops are usually aspirated, but unaspirated after `/s/` in a syllable onset.

Answer (score 1):

In Korean, such allophonic variation in consonant aspiration is normal.

Korean has a three-way contrast in its stops and affricates: "plain/lenis", "tense/fortis", "aspirated". In the Hangeul script, they have different representations, e.g.

- /k/ **ㄱ**, in Revised Romanisation *"g"*.
- /k͈/ **ㄲ** (frequently transcribed /k*/), in RR *"kk"*.
- /kʰ/ **ㅋ**, in RR *"k"*.

These are strongly distinguished in the word-initial/post-consonantal and intervocalic positions (기 *gi* *"energy/spirit"*, 끼 *kki* *"talent"/"classifier for meal"*, 키 *ki* *"height"*), with a combination of phonetic factors. Loudness, VOT, vowel *F*<sub>0</sub> all contribute, and they do so differently in the different environments.

However, at the end of a syllable, especially in the pre-consonantal position (forming small consonant clusters), the difference in the stops is [neutralised](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1013.9386&rep=rep1&type=pdf), as the stop is ***unreleased***. E.g. 부엌 /puʌ̹k̚/ *bueok* *"kitchen"* ends in the aspirated morphophoneme |kʰ|, but the standard pronunciation when said alone is to pronounce the final plosive unreleased [k̚], just the same as if it were written 부억 - indeed, Korean monolingual dictionaries will frequently retranscribe words in this way.

Nonetheless, when these words gain final particles, e.g. with the direct object marker it becomes 부엌을 *bueokeul*, the environment becomes an intervocalic one and the aspiration distinction is retained (although there is growing evidence with 부엌에 *bueoke* *"in the kitchen"* to suggest that [even this is eroding](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=vTuB12nR3qEC&oi=fnd&pg=PA37)).